# Client sends informations to server and saves to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0, client-server, lan

In my C# app client should send logs to server and the same logs must be save in SQL Server database.
How should I do this:

- client saves log in DB and server read from DB - rather not (long delay)
- client saves log in DB and simultaneously sends them to the server
- client only send to server and server saves them in DB

which way is more correct?

EDIT
There's many clients in the LAN network

Comment: "More correct" by which criteria?

Comment: I do not want to generate unnecessary network traffic

Comment: Between which two points? The client and the server? The client and the DB? The server and the DB? You can only eliminate one of those three.

Comment: Do you really need to store the log in both the database and on the server (assuming in a file)?

Comment: I don't know which way is faster. I think should eliminate unnecessary  traffic between client and server but i'm not sure

Comment: Yes. database is needed later as the story and server must have this log at once to take appropriate action against the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the client communicate only with the server.  The server would analyze the information from the client.  The server then writes the information to the database and/or takes action on the client.  This way you get the ability to immediately act on the client and save the information in the database for possible use later.  It also makes sense because then only one computer is able to write to SQL instead of your many clients all writing individually...

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is a no-go! Never do a single thing twice.

I'd say if your client already connects (and writes) to the database then your client should also write any logs directly into the database. (Option 1). In any other case option 3 seems the most appropriate.